# Testing Nokogiri XML generation with blank nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, minitest

I'm having a bit of trouble testing some XML generation using Nokogiri when the node is blank. I'm using Minitest to compare the generated XML string with a template fixture file. My test fails with the blank node as Minitest is comparing `<Node></Node>` with `<Node />`.

**XML Generation**

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new encoding: "UTF-8" do |xml|
  xml.Header
  xml.FileName @object.filename
end
```

**Template file**

This is the file I'm using as a fixture in my tests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Header/>
  <FileName></FileName>
```

**Minitest output**

```
3) Failure:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@
       <Header />
-          <FileName/>
+          <FileName></FileName>
```

As you can see, MiniTest is trying to compare a self-closing tag with a non-self-closing tag and making the test fail. Changing the fixture tag to a self-closing one results, strangely, in exactly the same error message.

It's because sometimes `@object.filename` is nil - if I have a blank XML node (as in `xml.Header` above) using a self-closing tag in my fixture works no problem.

Comment: You are asking us why your test failed, but not providing the source of your test?

Answer (score 0):

I would use XML schema in this case:

```
def test_that_xml_data_conforms_to_schema
  xml_data = ...
  schema_data = ...
  fragment = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_data)                                                                                     
  schema = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(schema_data)                                                                                  
  assert schema.valid?(fragment)
end
```